# How to don't "list folders before files" on Nautilus Trash and Downloads folders?

Tags: nautilus

On the Nautilus Trash and Downloads folders I have set to sort files on inverse modification time sort, but this way I can't be able to know if a folder is older that a file or not. Disabling the 'list folders before files' on the Nautilus preferences panel solve the trick, but it does globally and on normal folders it's a little mess to look for the folders between the files, since I got used to have them on top.

So, there's any way to enable this functionality only on this folders instead of globally in the same way that sort method, list/icon view and so are remembered in a per folder way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're saying. Sadly there is no way to do this; you must do it globally in the preferences as you have.

My suggestion: If you need to know if a folder is newer/older than a file, you could set it to the List view (which shows some details on the files) and arrange the items by modification date. That would probably be the closest to what you're looking for.

Comment: Nice suggestion :-) I've take a look and in fact I have had the trash on List View, with the advantage that it has a column showing the original position :-P Unluckily, if you enabled the "list folders before files" it also show them before :-( I'll leave it this way since it's useful, but I'll try to see if I got a better solution to accept it :-)

Comment: Since there's no better solution and at this moment this is working for me, I've accept your answer. Thank you so much for the tip! :-)